# Home internet periodically stops working for several minutes at a time

Tags: router, home-networking, internet-connection

I've been experiencing this problem with my internet connection for a few months. The internet goes down for 2-5 minutes, then comes back up with no intervention. This happens regularly, about twice a day.

During this time, I can ping my router (IP address `10.0.0.1`), but I cannot ping any external address (like `google.com` or `4.2.2.1`). When I connect to the router's web interface, I can look at the router's settings, but the online status displays `not connected`.

What could be happening here? Can I reasonably debug this, or is it a problem with my ISP's end?

Comment: I assume you're on a DSL based service (connected to a phone line) ? Your modem is losing sync, this is somethng you need to troubleshoot with your provider not SU.

Comment: I never heard of this term before, how did you come up with this hypothesis?

Comment: I had an ISP like that once. After their distribution box was hit by lightning (the whole street prayed for it, thank God), it got replaced and works fine now. The problem with calling the ISP's hotline is that they always ask you to reboot everything, and as that takes longer than the outage, it afterwards works fine, so they always blame your stuff for it.

Comment: @unknown I worked for an ISP. Their authentication server can see every time it happens (they probably only store 2-3 days worth of logs), just call them, they'll know whats going on an troubleshoot it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an upstream problem.  The fact that your router says `not connected` is the giveaway.

Finding out more info or getting it resolved is going to be a much more tricky beast.  You could have a hardware problem, a ISP problem, or maybe some attackers are trying to pwn your modem/router.  Or it could be "sunspots", or even actual sunspots.

**Hardware**

Start with the basics and make sure that your power adapter is good, you have a surge protector, your cables are in good working order, etc.  This includes the incoming cable from your ISP, and may go outside.  You may want to get your ISP to inspect the cable from their end to your modem.

You didn't specify your ISP type.  If you have a cable modem, you can access signal strength info and other diagnostic information from the web page built into the modem [DSL reports has a page that walk you through the process.](https://www.dslreports.com/faq/7363)

If you own your own modem, do you have the latest version?  DOCIS 3 is rolling out, and your ISP may not like your DOCISS 2 modem.  I'm sure there is a comparison for DSL too.

**ISP**

If you have a crappy ISP, like most of us, they will just tell you to reboot some stuff and then by that time they may reboot some stuff on their end and things will be working again.  Oftentimes, the outage or problem will go away by the time you get to talk to a real person.

However, if you're hitting a data cap, they think you are doing something they don't want you to (Video consumption, VPN usage, BitTorrent, etc), they may be doing underhanded things to get you to stop or to get your attention.

**Attackers**

There is router malware:

- [Computer World: Update: Malware-infected home routers used to launch DDoS attacks](http://www.computerworld.com/article/2921559/malware-vulnerabilities/malware-infected-home-routers-used-to-launch-ddos-attacks.html)
- [Ars Technica: Bizarre attack infects Linksys routers with self-replicating malware](http://arstechnica.com/security/2014/02/bizarre-attack-infects-linksys-routers-with-self-replicating-malware/)
- [PCWorld: How to protect your wireless router from malware](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2880189/watch-out-for-malware-on-your-router.html)

Your modem or router could be coming under attack and that glitch is the device going down or shutting down the port to protect itself.